# How do I know if a JSON string has loaded?

Tags: ajax, json, jquery

Forgive me, I am a complete JSON newbie here. I'm trying to load a file of json information from an external file, and I'm not sure how I can tell if the information has loaded or not. Here's what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(string) {
            data = $.parseJSON(string);
            console.log(data);
            alert(data);
            document.write(data);
        },
        url: 'http://www.site.com/mystuff.php'
    });  
});
```

I've tried putting all kinds of stuff to see if the  info has loaded, as you can see, and nothing has. How do I know if I've even gotten anything? I would really appreciate any help!

Comment: There is no need in `parseJSON` if you set the data type as `"json"`.

Comment: Implement the error handler to confirm that your ajax call is even working.

Comment: I don't think you'd have to use `parseJSON` if you set dataType to json. Try using `function(data)` instead of `function(string)` and see if you get any data.

Comment: @Lian It doesn't matter what he calls the param going into the callback function; however, I do agree that `parseJSON` is not needed.

Comment: No need of parsing the data that is already in json ... This should do   console.log(data); without parsing it

Comment: So what I want to write is this?

Comment: Thanks for your patience with a total newbie. I tried this:   $(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        // do something
   console.log(data);
    },
    url: 'http://www.site.com/mystuff.php'
});

  });

Comment: This didn't work on Chrome. I'll try looking up how to do the error handler. Does it matter that I'm coding locally and the file I want to reference is located on a remote server?

Answer (score 1):

As already pointed out, two things:

- You don't need to parse the string when setting the datatype as JSON
- Check if the request returned successfully at all

Which could look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error : function(xhr, text) {
            console.log('An error occurred', xhr, text);
        },
        url: 'http://www.site.com/mystuff.php'
    });  
});
```

When setting the datatype to JSON you also have to make sure that mystuff.php sets the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`:

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
?>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! The external file is actually a php file hosted elsewhere that I can't edit. Does this mean that I should run the ajax another way, setting the dataType to something else?

Comment: If it is hosted on a different domain you will have the entirely different problem of the same origin policy restriction.

Comment: Just what I needed! :) Fortunately, I checked, and I am allowed to copy the remote file down locally. I saved it as test.php , with the <?php header code you recommended on top. I tried using the error handling code below, and got an alert with an error message.

Comment: This is what the code was: $(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend : function() {
           console.log('Before Ajax Request Starts !!');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert(data);
            document.write(data);
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             alert("Error occurred: " + errorThrown);
        },
         beforeSend : function() {
           console.log('Ajax Request Complete  !!');
        },
        url: 'test.php'
    });  
});

Comment: The original file I'm trying to reference is here: http://www.pbs.org/pov/film-list.php The local test.php file I created is the same, only with the <?php header code on top.

Answer (score 0):

No need to parse to json again.. you can directly use the object
Also add the error Function to keep a check if you are getting any error..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend : function() {
           console.log('Before Ajax Request Starts !!');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            alert(data);
            document.write(data);
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             alert("Error occurred: " + errorThrown);
        },
         beforeSend : function() {
           console.log('Ajax Request Complete  !!');
        },
        url: 'http://www.site.com/mystuff.php'
    });  
});
```

This makes sure you have feedback at every step..

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! This is my first ever attempt to do anything in JSON. I'm getting an "Error occured" message. The file I'm attempting to reference is an external file that I can't edit. It's here: http://www.pbs.org/pov/film-list.php . This means I can't set the content type to <?php
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
?> . Does this mean there's another way I should run the query? Again, thank you so much for your help!